# Extending the Euclidean division for positive integers to all integers

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

I have already proved the euclidean division for positive integers as follows:

Theorem:
[image: Theorem for positive integers]
Proof:[image]
I want to extend this to all integers with the following theorem and proof[image]

But it doesn't seem right. Can anyone tell me the blunder in my proofs or suggest something better? I am sorry for too many images or if this is a duplicated question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lemma is clearly false, since if $b<0,$ then there is *no* $-b < r < b.$

Comment: Yeah. Thanks! You think that changing the inequality to $0\le r < |b|$ should make it correct? But then how should the proof go?

Comment: @Jainul If $b$ is negative, multiply both $a$ and $b$ by $-1$ to reduce to the case where $b$ is positive. If $a$ is negative (and $b$ is now positive) add $r b$ so that $a+rb$ is positive. That reduces to the $a, b$ positive cse.